# Multiple join with a group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I have three tables.
MainTable

```
HospitalId City  Data
1           1     20
1           1     10
2           2     50
3           3     100
```

Hospital

```
HospitalId, Staff
1            5
2            30
3            10
```

City

```
CityId City
1       Delhi
2       New York
3       Mumbai
```

I need to find the percentageform the city

ResultTable

```
City         Staff  Total Percentage
Delhi          10    30     
New York       30    50
Mumbai         10    100
```

I try doing the cound but It dosnt work with the group by clause.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the logic to get the results you have?

Comment: Try my answer, hope ti helps you.

Comment: How is "Total Percentage' calculated?

Comment: Your MainTable has 2 rows showing HospitalId = 1, City = 1.  What is the meaning of "Data" in that table?  Its not clear what you are asking for.  Do you want the percentage of total staff, by city?  Your example Result table shows Delhi, staff = 10, "total percentage" = 30, but 30 is the total number of staff in Delhi, it is NOT the percentage of staff in Dehli, at least not according to the data you have presented.

Comment: data column is the sales.I need to find the sales Percentage related to each city.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is:

> I need to find the percentage from the city

However, your results suggest a basic aggregation query:

```
select c.City, sum(h.Staff) as staff, sum(m.Data) as Total_Percentage
from City c join
     MainTable c
     on m.City = c.CityId join
     Hospital h
     on h.HospitalId = m.HospitalId
group by c.City;
```

I would not describe this query as returning the percentage from each city.  But I don't know what `data` means either.